# How to perform Find/FindNext operation in Notepad C# winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, programmers-notepad

Please anyone suggest me some ideas regarding how to perform find/findNext operation in notepad program in C#. I want to search for all occurrence of strings in RichTextBox and highlight each occurrence on click of findNext button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may take a look at this code : http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2466.htm and for hightlighting [Highlight text in TextBox/Label/RichTextBox using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027358/highlight-text-in-textbox-label-richtextbox-using-c)

Answer (score 0):

I created a notepad clone in C# that implements the find / findnext operation identical to Window's notepad. You can find the source here:

http://www.simplygoodcode.com/2012/04/notepad-clone-in-net-winforms.html

Here is what the code for the function looks like in the application:

```
    private string _LastSearchText;
    private bool _LastMatchCase;
    private bool _LastSearchDown;

    public bool FindAndSelect(string pSearchText, bool pMatchCase, bool pSearchDown) {
        int Index;

        var eStringComparison = pMatchCase ? StringComparison.CurrentCulture : StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;

        if (pSearchDown) {
            Index = Content.IndexOf(pSearchText, SelectionEnd, eStringComparison);
        } else {
            Index = Content.LastIndexOf(pSearchText, SelectionStart, SelectionStart, eStringComparison);
        }

        if (Index == -1) return false;

        _LastSearchText = pSearchText;
        _LastMatchCase = pMatchCase;
        _LastSearchDown = pSearchDown;

        SelectionStart = Index;
        SelectionLength = pSearchText.Length;

        return true;
    }
```

This method is on the main form. It accounts for the options in the "Find" dialog box. It stores the parameter values in order to be able to perform a "Find Next"/F3 later. Several of the properties you see like `SelectionStart`, `SelectionLength`, and `Content` are essentially aliases to the the `TextBox`'s `SelectionStart`, `SelectionLength`, and `Text` properties.